# How do I restore my rooted Motorola Droid back to completely stock and unrooted?

Tags: motorola-droid, unrooting

I'm thinking about unrooting and going back to completely stock, vanilla Android on my Droid.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2):

This website has a very good answer:
http://www.droidforums.net/forum/droid-hacks/13466-how-back-stock-no-su-no-busybox-etc.html

Seems to cover all your bases.

Essentially involves:

- flashing the stock recovery and boot images to replace custom ones
- then either

  - manually removing all the "root" bits, or
  - (option B in the post) flashing the official update.zip putting your phone back to stock!

Good luck :)

Answer (score 0):

This is a stab in the dark, that I read somewhere else:

> Power + X
>
> Volume up + Camera button
>
> And in the menu select reset to
>   factory defaults?
>
> I'm assuming this is going to take you
>   back to ver 2.0 without root, without
>   any apps, contacts or anything else
>   you've done to your phone.
>
> Granted, I don't know this for sure
>   but its typically how all devices work
>   *eyes his old ipod video* I've reset that thing so many times with a
>   'restore' and it always removes any
>   hacks I've done to it.

I'd be interested to find out how this works after the phone has been rooted.

Comment: I accidently did this with my eris, so what will happen is that you'll be back to stock rom and factory settings, but still rooted.  Rooting goes outside of the normal boundries, so it's not covered by the factory reset.

Answer (score 0):

This code is used for factory format. It'll remove all files and settings including the internal memory storage. It'll also reinstall the phone firmware, which should remove your root!

Once you give this code, there is no way to cancel the operation unless you remove the battery from the phone. So think twice before giving this code.

Enter this: ***2767*3855#**

in the dialer.